# Hide navigation buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm developing a WPF .NET 4.0 application.

When I moving from page to page, the navigation toolbar is showing. 
But I really don't want to.

I every page I've set :

```
ShowsNavigationUI="False"
```

When I change the page, this is showing:

[image]

Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Add `NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"`

Comment: I get  : "The member "NavigationUIVisibility" is not recognized or is not accessible"

Comment: Well that shouldn't be. I wonder if that's a 4.0 thing, will swing back to this in a bit. (I didn't think about the 4.0 part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a frame to navigate between pages? if so:

```
<Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Content="Frame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

Notice the NavigationUIVisibility set to Hidden.

-Edit: You can use this in .NET 4.0 (I have used it.)